# The most recent request was denied because it contained an invalid security token. Please refresh the page and try again

Tags: session, joomla

We are getting error message, when a user trying to logged in our Joomla website.

"The most recent request was denied because it contained an invalid security token. Please refresh the page and try again."

So far.

1. i have cleared sessions from phpmyadmin
2. Cleared cache

Above mentioned all are temporary solution. Everyday i am getting same error. i need to do above things to rectify.

Is there any permanent fix for this.

Comment: Check this link it may help https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/tutorials/361?utm_source=Alledia&utm_campaign=a0292c0a93-The_Alledia_Newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_80803af9fd-a0292c0a93-270277273&goal=0_80803af9fd-a0292c0a93-270277273&mc_cid=a0292c0a93&mc_eid=0955cb49f8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you see the invalid token message, the solution is simple:
>
> - Go to Extension > Manage > Database.
> - Click "Fix".

---

Source: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17356/joomla-3-6-0-to-3-6-1-results-in-a-invalid-security-token-error

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk, what is your "Session Handler" in "Global Configuration?"